# Is there any device that can capture a picture into 3D model?

Tags: modeling

I am currently wondering is there any way or device that can transform a picture into 3D model automatically?

or a machine learning thing to learn from picture (2D) into 3D model?

Comment: Have you researched holograms?

Comment: hi, not yet, will do it from now. thanks for the advise

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, how can I invite you to a chat?

Comment: Yes, there are computer programs that can utilize multiple photos to create a 3D model. What is your question? Please note that asking for program recommendations is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Yes, but none of them work well on faces. Though a structured light emitter camera combo will. There is a ai system that can do tgis from one image too. the results are ok for a game but nothing serious.

Answer (score 1):

Look up '3D scanners'. There are plenty of such devices, professional and amateur, for small items, microscopic, and for architecture, from complex and precise to as simple as [apps for a smartphone](https://all3dp.com/2/5-best-3d-scanner-apps-for-your-smartphone/). There are also programs that can transform a series of photos into a model, and ones that aid manual 3D modelling with use of a single photo (where you manually add depth).

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps with variety of precision for the cellphones.

I had one that required a series of photos taken from around a real object.

It will then turn it into a mesh frame and render it as you like, with warped texted over the faces for example. I deleted it due to memory consumption.

Google without too much fanfare is stitching all the photos from defferent angle taken at deferent scales in social media and is creating 3d cities. If you check on Google map or Google earth, you see some cities are now populated with real 3d objects such as ships on ports or airplanes, aside from the buildings which were already there. I guess their goal is to digitise the whole world eventually.